# What's the function of search_index file in graphite?

Tags: graphite

I'm playing with graphite, and I met a problem which is graphite is not showing any metrics, even though I have feed it some data, and the data is stored in whisper. I guess this is caused by search_index file.

```
daniel@ubuntu:/var/lib/graphite$ ls -lh
total 72K
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data  www-data   64K Jul  4 21:49 graphite.db
-rw-r----- 1 _graphite _graphite    0 Jul  5 23:17 search_index
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data  www-data  4.0K Feb  2 02:33 whisper
```

What's the purpose of this file, who generated it and how change the ownership of it? graphite can not read it because of permission.

graphite complains :

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/graphite/search_index'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this search_index file is the index used by webapp of graphite. My problem was caused by conflict between graphite in ubuntu package repo and python PYPI repo. first I install graphite by 'apt-get install' and then I use 'pip install' to install graphite again. These 2 commands will install graphite at different places, and apt-get will installs graphite at standard python library path, this will cause some subtle conflict to graphite installed by pip.

Today, I installed it with pip only on a new machine, everything works OK.